# Proyecto App Android studio crashea cuando termina carga de listview

Tags: java, android, json, restful

buenas tardes comunidad, y feliz año
quisiera consultar el porque de cuando termino la carga de un listview mediante un servicio en mi proyecto, en vez de mostrarse, la app crashea directamente? 
el testeo lo estoy haciendo con un moto G4 plus (por si tiene algo que ver, en su edicion de 2GB de ram)
y los archivos principales que estoy usando son estos

Servicio

```
public class Servicio {

public ArrayList<Locales> GetData(){
    JSONArray JsonArr = null;
    ArrayList<Locales> locales = new ArrayList<Locales>();
    String dir = "http://192.168.0.3:8081/locales";
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

    URL url;
    HttpURLConnection connection;
    try
    {
        url = new URL(dir);
        connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        connection.connect();

        BufferedReader ent = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
        String line = null;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
        String json = "";
        while((line = ent.readLine()) != null)
        {
            response.append(line);
        }
        json = response.toString();
        JsonArr = new JSONArray(json);
        for (int i= 0; i<JsonArr.length();i++ ){
            JSONObject JsonObject = JsonArr.getJSONObject(i);
            Locales locales1 = new Locales();
            locales1.Nombre = JsonObject.optString("Nombre");
            locales1.Direccion = JsonObject.optString("Direccion");
            locales1.Valuacion = JsonObject.optInt("Valuacion");
            locales.add(locales1);
        }

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return locales;
}
```

Adaptador

```
public class LocalesAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Locales> {
private ArrayList<Locales> objects;
private Context mContext;

public LocalesAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Locales> objects) {
    super(context, 0, objects);
    this.mContext = context;
    this.objects = objects;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

    View v = convertView;
    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
    }
    Locales i = objects.get(position);

    if (i != null) {
        TextView tt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.toptext);
        TextView ttd = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.toptextdata);
        TextView mt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.middletext);
        TextView mtd = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.middletextdata);
        TextView bt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.bottomtext);
        TextView btd = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.desctext);

        // check to see if each individual textview is null.
        // if not, assign some text!
        if (tt != null){
            tt.setText("Nombre: ");
        }
        if (ttd != null){
            ttd.setText(i.getNombre());
        }
        if (mt != null){
            mt.setText("Direccion: ");
        }
        if (mtd != null){
            mtd.setText("$" + i.getDireccion());
        }
        if (bt != null){
            bt.setText("Valuacion: ");
        }
        if (btd != null){
            btd.setText(i.getValuacion());
        }
    }

    // the view must be returned to our activity
    return v;

}
```

Main

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private WebSocketClient mWebSocketClient = null;
private Runnable viewParts = null;
private LocalesAdapter m_adapter= null;
private ArrayList<Locales> listaLocales = new ArrayList<Locales>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.mainListView);
    Servicio ser = new Servicio();
    listaLocales = ser.GetData();
    m_adapter = new LocalesAdapter(this, listaLocales);
    lv.setAdapter(m_adapter);
}
```

el tema es que justamente, el compilador no muestra ningun error, es mas, termina toda la ejecucion, pero por algun motivo, el debugger no me carga los logs del dispositivo, y si lo ejecuto en el emulador, se me crashea el emulador por el hardware de mi maquina, que no le da la potencia para correrlo correctamente

Comment: Intenta editar tu pregunta y solo deja el codigo relevante y mira el logcat cuando te ocurra el error que te dira con mas detalle donde se cerro la app.

Comment: el tema es justamente eso, que cuando lo ejecuto desde el movil, no me muestra el logcat por algun motivo, y si intento ejecutarlo desde el emulador, este ultimo se me crashea el propio emulador (por falta de recursos) antes de abrir la app

Comment: No podemos adivinar que te pasa , concta tu telefono por usb y fijate el logcat

Comment: Cuando haces super(context, 0, objects); en el constructor de tu adapter porque le pasas 0? Pásale el layout de tu adapter con R.layout.locales_adapter.xml o como se llame en tu caso

Comment: es que lo copie de un tutorial que estaba viendo, lo corrijo y aviso!, gracias por el dato @PabloSimonDiEstefano

Comment: Ok y comenta que tal te ha ido

Comment: muchas gracias @PabloSimonDiEstefano, principalmente ese era el problema, ahi publique la respuesta, ya que no era solamente eso, pero era un 50% del fallo

Comment: me alegro, ánimo programando

Answer (score 0):

Gracias a los comentarios de @PabloSimonDiEstefano, primero, tenia los siguientes problemas:

> Cuando haces super(context, 0, objects); en el constructor de tu adapter >porque le pasas 0? Pásale el layout de tu adapter con R.layout.locales_adapter.xml o como se llame en tu caso

y el otro problema, es que me tiraba un error en el adaptador, cuando le pasaba la valuacion del local que tenia, parece que no me encontraba el textlabel, y eso me crasheaba la app tambien

```
        if (bt != null){
        bt.setText("Valuacion: ");
    }
    if (btd != null){
        btd.setText(i.getValuacion());
    }
```

temporalmente, comente este fragmento de codigo para continuar y luego corregirlo